# Using a VIEW to group-by and SUM

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data, let's take a sample;

| Currency | Account | FiatValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BTC | Account1 | 10 |
| ETH | Account2 | 6 |
| BTC | Account2 | 10 |

Is there any way I can use a `view` to aggregate this in some way. I'd like to end up with an aggregate view of all `Accounts` and their total `FiatValue` across all Currencies. I was thinking of writing some `PowerShell` to grab the data in this table, and update a new table via a script, but thought possibly I can achieve something similar within SQL?

Goal

| Account | FiatValue |
| --- | --- |
| Account1 | 10 |
| Account2 | 16 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can write a SQL query, you can save it as a View.  This one is very simple:

```
create or alter view AccountSummary
as
select AccountId, sum(FiatValue) FiatValue
from Account
group by AccountId
```